# How do you define a node and an edge when talking about McCabes Complexity?

Tags: testing, test-coverage

I am trying to understand the formula, but I am a bit in doubt how exactly you define edges and nodes.

Edges seem to be every possible exit from a statement and nodes seem to be statements, is this definition wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of nodes as statement blocks that do not have control flow statements and edges as individual paths that lead to other statement blocks because of control flow statements.

For example:

```
print "A"
if(dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday)
  print "B"
print "C"
```

Would have three nodes, print "A", print "B" and print "C" And three edges A to B, B to C and A to C.